# How to show a Iframe in 100% height

Tags: html, css, iframe

I want to show a iFrame on one of my page with 100% height.

But When i add height 100% to the iFrame, it only gets 100px of height.

The codes i add to the iFrame is here:

```
<iframe src="http://carlist.bilinfo.dk/31282" style="border: none;" width="940" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
```

The page is: http://www.storgaardbiler.dk/brugte-biler/

I've tried to add html, 'body{height 100%}' but that did not help.

Comment: What do you exactly mean? I just checked it out and the iframe is over 100px in height.

Comment: it will only 100% to the space your're putting it into.

Comment: I'v made it 100% again. Why does it not show the hole iframe?

Comment: @user2064285 because the iframe doesn't know how big the data is inside it. You need to know the dimensions of what is in the iframe and then size your iframe to that of the content

Comment: Ehm.. the dimension of what is inside the iframe is gonna change. Its a car dealer site. And the iFrame is showing all the used car he is selling. And when you click on a car the iframe is only about 800px, and the "front page" of the iframe is 10350px

Comment: the content of your iframe is also from cross domain so you cannot access the height of inner content of iframe

Answer (score 0):

height: 100% will work with position: absolute 
so give position absolute to iframe. give position relative to outer container/div and provide height or fixed height to outer container. Now the iframe will expand upto the height 
of its parent/outer container.

Fix the height of parent div/container 
make parent div/container position:relative 
now give position: absolute to iframe

Comment: Will it be good to make a new div box around the Iframe?
I have tried the other that you said, but It does not work:/

Comment: 100% height means it will take the height of its parent having position relative/fixed. So it is necessary to give a parent div around the iframe with fixed height so that it can expand upto that height. That div must have position relative/fixed. Better to use relative position for parent div.

Answer (score 0):

Add this into your css code
`iframe{`
`width{100%;`
`}`